# Limit vsftpd Writes

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have a vsftpd installation running on Ubuntu 11.04. I have two users, an external user and an internal user. I only want the internal user to have write/upload permissions, but I want both to have read/download permissions. How do I accomplish this? I have already set `write_enable=YES` in the config, but that allows all users to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haver a look at the `user_config_dir` directive.

> This powerful option allows the
>   override of any config option
>   specified in the manual page, on a
>   per-user basis. Usage is simple, and
>   is best illustrated with an example.
>   If you set user_config_dir to be
>   /etc/vsftpd_user_conf and then log on
>   as the user "chris", then vsftpd will
>   apply the settings in the file
>   /etc/vsftpd_user_conf/chris for the
>   duration of the session. The format of
>   this file is as detailed in this
>   manual page

e.g.

```
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/user_config
```

You should be able to create a file for the external user and specify

`write_enable=NO`

in it to stop their ability to write.